# Array of Embedded Documents YiiMongoDbSuite

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

I have three classes. The course consists of the stages. The stages consists of the steps.

```
class Course extends EMongoDocument{
....
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return array(
            'embeddedArrays' => array(
                'class'=>'ext.YiiMongoDbSuite.extra.EEmbeddedArraysBehavior',
                'arrayPropertyName'=>'stages',
                'arrayDocClassName'=>'Stage'
            ),
        );
    }
}

class Stage extends EMongoEmbeddedDocument{
...
    public function behaviors()
{
        return array(
            'embeddedArrays' => array(
                'class'=>'ext.YiiMongoDbSuite.extra.EEmbeddedArraysBehavior',
                'arrayPropertyName'=>'steps',
                'arrayDocClassName'=>'Step'
            ),
        );
}
class Step extends EMongoEmbeddedDocument{
...
}
```

In mongodb i have data:

```
{
    "name" : "course1",
    "online" : "0",
    "author_id" : ObjectId("521df3f1e405688411000029"),
    "approved" : false,
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("521dfd84e40568d80900002a"),
            "name" : null,
            "steps" : null,
            "price" : null
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5220c648e40568701c000031"),
            "name" : null,
            "steps" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5220c648e40568701c000032"),
                    "name" : null
                }
            ],
            "price" : null
        }
    ],
    "short_description" : "test",
    "_id" : ObjectId("521dfd7ce40568d809000029")
}
```

When i try read data from mongodb:
Fatal error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object in ****extensions\YiiMongoDbSuite\extra\EEmbeddedArraysBehavior.php on line 104

```
$arrayOfDocs[] = $doc->toArray();
```

If stage not have steps all works fine. What i do wrong?

Comment: It's probably bug, have you tried some other version of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be multiple versions of [YiiMongoDbSuite](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/) on GitHub. Are you using v1.3.6.3 of [canni/YiiMongoDbSuite](https://github.com/canni/YiiMongoDbSuite)?

Looking at the `beforeToArray()` method in [EEmbeddedArraysBehavior.php](https://github.com/canni/YiiMongoDbSuite/blob/master/extra/EEmbeddedArraysBehavior.php), the code seems to access the property and then immediately iterator over it. If the `stages.0.steps` field in your document is `null`, I don't see how the first `is_array()` check in the behavior code will pass. I would suggest debugging the function and inspecting the value of the `stages` property around where it is saved to the `_cache` property and before the `foreach()` iteration. My guess is that it may be an array with a single element whose value is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. While filling values for embedded document fields it gets an array (what to fill) from function attributeNames() of that embedded document, then **flip** it and so on. So to fix NULL values you should fill in the return array of that function. My code will help you:

```
<?php
class Pricing extends EMongoEmbeddedDocument {
    public $setup;
    public $monthly;
    public $annually;
    public function rules() {
        return array(
        );
    }
    public function attributeNames() {
        return array(
            'setup' => 'setup',
            'monthly' => 'monthly',
            'annually' => 'annually'
        );
    }
}
```

also this code

```
public function setAttributes($values, $safeOnly=true)
    {
        if(!is_array($values))
            return;

        if($this->hasEmbeddedDocuments())
        {
            $attributes=array_flip($safeOnly ? $this->getSafeAttributeNames() : $this->attributeNames());

            foreach($this->embeddedDocuments() as $fieldName => $className)
                $this->$fieldName = new $className;
                if(isset($values[$fieldName]) && isset($attributes[$fieldName]))
                {
                    $this->$fieldName->setAttributes($values[$fieldName], $safeOnly);
                    unset($values[$fieldName]);
                }
        }

        parent::setAttributes($values, $safeOnly);
    }
```

helped me to prevent fatal error Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttributes() on a non-object in EMongoDocument.php